# Regex to return multi lines between two WORDS - Powershell

Tags: powershell, regex

I am trying to use the following regex:

```
(?<=----Old-------\n)(((.+\n)+)\n*?)(?=__________________________________________)
```

to get multi lines betwords

```
----Old-------
250096 - LT Security Role: Read Only, 250032 - Sales VIC3, 250083 -
Security Role: Base Security Role, 250080 - Security Role: Payment
Allocation, 250058 - Security Role: TFM Sales Consultant, 250103 - Web
Fleet SuperUser
```

---

But the select-string is not returning anything.

I used https://regex101.com/ and https://www.regexpal.com/ and the Regex is working as expected.

could you please help.

```
$ModifyOldRegex = "(?<=----Old-------\n)(((.+\n)+)\n*?)(?=__________________________________________)"    
$Description | Select-String  -Pattern $ModifyOldRegex.matches.Value
```

[image]

Comment: try this: `select-string -pattern $ModifyOldRegex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }`

Answer (score 1):

**Finally I found the problem:**

1- Use get-Content -Raw for the \n to work // I am not sure why

2- Changed the Regex to

"(?<=----Old-------)((.+\n)+)(?=__________________________________________)"